# To find a column name in a specific column and enter its number

Tags: python, pandas

Python.
I'm going to use a pandas
Locate the column name from column 1.
Locate the column name in the text entered in column 0 and enter the number as a number.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['EA',0,0,0], ['col2,col2', 0, 0,0], ['col3', 0,0,0]]
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[0, 'EA', 'col2', 'col3'])
df_input

data = [['EA',1,0,0], ['col2,col2', 0, 2,0], ['col3', 0,0,1]]
df_output = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[0, 'EA', 'col2', 'col3'])
df_output
```

Comment: please improve formatting

Comment: Is `col2,col3` a valid value in `data`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) then a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = (df_input[0]
     .str.extractall('([^,]+)')[0]
     .droplevel(-1)
     )

# update in place
df_input.update(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))
```

Or for a new DataFrame:

```
df_output = (pd.crosstab(s.index, s)
               .combine_first(df_input)
               .reindex_like(df_input)
             )
```

Output:

```
           0  EA  col2  col3
0         EA   1     0     0
1  col2,col2   0     2     0
2       col3   0     0     1
```

Output if `col2,col2` was `col2,col3`:

```
           0  EA  col2  col3
0         EA   1     0     0
1  col2,col3   0     1     1
2       col3   0     0     1
```

Comment: What if it was `col2,col3` instead of `col2,col2`?

Comment: @Nick then you'll get 1 for each

Comment: Cool, I was confused by the `[0]` on the `extractall`

Comment: Yes I wish `extractall` had an `expand=False` option like `extract` ;)

Comment: Yeah, seems like a logical thing to do...

Comment: My problem is solved exactly. (first for me.)
Thank you very much.